# sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type boolean: "sdzf"

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm making a function in my e-commerce website which updates credentials of a user. whenever my form triggers this function I get the error -> sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type boolean: "sdzf"

I'm unable to find out what's wrong. Please help me find the issue. Thanks in advance.

python code:

```
@app.route("/admin_cred_update", methods=["POST","GET"])
def admin_cred_update():
    email=str(request.form.get("email"))
    password=str(request.form.get("password"))
    if re.search("[.,*/%$#:|\[\]\(\)]",email) and re.search("[.,*/%$#:|\[\]\(\)]",password):
        message="there are some invalid characters in above fields"
        return render_template("admin_profile.html", updatemes=message)
    else:
        db.execute("update admin_master_tbl SET email=:email and password=:password where email=:smail and password=:spassword",{"email":email,"password":password,"smail":session["adminname"],"spassword":session["adminpassword"]})
        session["adminname"]=email
        session["adminpassword"]=password
        message1="credentials updated succesfully"
        return render_template("admin_profile.html", updatemes=message1)
```

error log:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid   input syntax for type boolean: "sdzf"
LINE 1: update admin_master_tbl SET email='sdzf' and password='csadf...
                                          ^

[SQL: update admin_master_tbl SET email=%(email)s and password=%(password)s  where email=%(smail)s and password=%(spassword)s]
[parameters: {'email': 'sdzf', 'password': 'csadfc', 'smail': 'lightningdrago72@gmail.com', 'spassword': 'asdf'}]
```

Comment: Read the `psycopg2` docs for how to work with parameters, [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)

Comment: Hi @AdrianKlaver, I saw the docs and tried to use a different method but still I get the same error. Please check my code and error again I've made some changes.

Comment: What is schema definition for table `admin_master`?  Its looks like `email` field is of `boolean` type and you are trying to enter a string value in it.

Comment: No @AdrianKlaver, the email field is of varchar type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I found the problem!!. I did the mistake of putting `and` instead of `,` in the `SET` part of my query. Now the problem is solved!!.